# Had 2 big projects A,B. where A and B shares common code in the Project C , Structure those projects in TFS with GIT

Tags: .net, git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

**Problem with Commits to Visual Studio Team Services via GIT**

> we had two big projects lets Say A and B, and those two Projects A and
>   B uses(Refers) code from the Project C(Common).

The project structure is, all those three projects belongs to same parent directory(sibling folders).

When we upload this source code to the Visual Studio Team Services we creted 3 TeamProjects and each folder belongs to each Team Project.

**Problem:**- when we open the solution of project A and made changes to project C(because it was referenced to the Project A) and did a  Commit to Project A but the Project C wasn't showing those changes in the TFS commit.

**Need a Solution for the Structure in the Visual Studio Team Services /GIT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to have similar problems until we moved to using Nuget to manage shared code and dependencies.  Nuget offers versioning, dependency trees and a centralized store.  Its really easy to create packages and share them once you spend some time with it.  Check it out

https://docs.nuget.org/

Comment: Thanks for the information @chief7,
I will consider your solution